# Fetching ten ten records from JSON API in word press

Tags: plugin-json-api, json, web-services

I am using `JSON API` for getting web services.. I have 80 records in my `wp_posts` table .
I need to display 10 , 10 records so that my mobile  app will be faster.
I used the following method in this

```
http://mysite.com/api/?json=get_category_posts&slug=mediapr&count=84
```

here i get 84 records, if i specify my count to 10 , only ten records will be displayed but later on i need to fetch next ten records.

I searched json api documentation but dint find solution
What method should i use to do so..
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's the debug query arg: `?dev=1`, which you can simply append to the URl.

AFAIK, the plugin relies on [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), so you should be save to use `&offset=10`.

_Disclaimer: Not tested, as I ain't got a setup with the plugin in use.`